# @Autowired dosn't work into one controller in other method of the same controller works fine

Tags: java, spring, autowired, spring-restcontroller

@Autowired suddenly stop working when I added new @RequestMapping method into controller. Why I don't understand it. When I try to use this new method all @Autowired interface become null. When I use other @RequestMapping into other method all works perfectly.

[image]

First Image shows all @Autowired class is null when I try to use new @RequestMapping.

[image]

This I use other @RequestMapping all works perfectyl. This is spring Rest Api application. I've not encountered this things before. What might be behaving application like this.

Comment: I can see from first image, it doesn't have `@RestController` and none of the dependency is injected; it's all null. Is it there?

Comment: @Adarsh it is the same class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring creates your controller in the following manner:

1. Create an instance
2. Inject `@Autowired` dependencies
3. Wrap this instance with a Proxy, which handles the annotations, like `@PreAuthorize` or `@Transactional`, and then delegates the call to the real instance.

Due to the nature of the proxy library Spring is using (CGLIB) and also generally the java language itself. It is only allowed to overwrite `public` methods. Which, when looking at your example, makes sense.

Your method which is failing is annotated with `@PreAuthorize` and.... it is `private`, meaning: It was invoked on the proxy, and the proxy doesn't have the injected dependencies, because normally it would delegate to the real instance. But *because* it is a `private` method, cglib and java can't do that.

> By the way: When looking at your screenshots you can see that the `this` variable is different in both of your calls.